# Django rest framework get json instead of count

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a Community app with a field of subscriber related to the accounts app but in the response it return counts instead of using account serializer

CommunitySerializer:

```
class CommunitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Community
        fields = ('name', 'about', 'subscribers', 'moderators')
```

AccountsSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)
```

It Return:

```
{
"name": "pcmasterrace",
"about": "Welcome to the official subreddit of the PC Master Race. In this subreddit, we celebrate and promote the ultimate gaming and working platform. Ascend to a level that respects your eyes, your wallet, your mind, and your heart. Ascend to... the PC Master Race.",
"community_rules": [
    {
        "rule": "Rule 1 - Off Topic",
        "description": "DOnt fuck"
    },
    {
        "rule": "Rule 2 - No tech support",
        "description": "community_rulescommunity_rulescommunity_rulescommunity_rulescommunity_rules"
    }
],
"subscribers": [
    1
],
"moderators": [
    1
]
}
```

Comment: How does it return `community_rules` if that is not within the `serializer`?

Comment: i delete it for the question

Comment: Is it actually passing back a count or is it a list of `ForeignKey` primary keys?

Comment: its passing back a count of subscriber users

Comment: how is the subscribers field defined in Community model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of count, could 1 in

```
"subscribers": [
    1
],
```

be the id of the only subscriber? Either way, if you want to get **subscribers** as a list of **UserSerializer** instances, you need to define it explicitly in the serializer, otherwise DRF would use ids by default.

```
class CommunitySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subscribers = UserSerializer(many=True)
    ...
```